# Using remove function with an if statement in for loop doesn't remove all the elements

Tags: python, list, for-loop, if-statement

I was writing a very simple code to check a condition and remove elements from the list. the code is as below:

```
a=[1,2,10, 11, 12, 102, 106,107, 108, 109, 110]
for i in a :
    if i < 7.5 or i > 19.5:
        a.remove(i)
print(a)
```

The output comes out to be:
[2, 10, 11, 12, 106, 108, 110]

Why doesn't the remove function remove 2, 106, 108, 110? Is there a bug? How can it be fixed?

I expected that the result should have been [10,11,12] but these extra elements were in the result too.